# How to add "Please Select" to Javascript drop down

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

JavaScript populates Drop Down options from a SharePoint column and I need to add "Please Select" or blank that will not pass for NOT Null.

I tried adding a new item to the SharePoint list and .append to the JavaScript but neither gave the results I want.

```
function getReasons(ddlReason)
{
    $.ajax({ 
       url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Reason for Rejection')/Items?$orderby=Title", 
       type: "GET", 
       async: false,
       headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}, 
       success: function (data) { 
          if (data != undefined && data.d != undefined && data.d.results != undefined && data.d.results.length > 0) { 
          /////////////
            $.each(data.d.results, function( index, value ) 
            {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = value.Title;
                option.value = value.Id;
                ddlReason.appendChild(option);
            });
        } 
       }, 
       error: function (xhr) { 
          alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText); 
       } 
    }); 
}=
```

I am getting the options from SharePoint...
"Bad Image"
"Coding"

I want to add to the top of the options a...
"Please Select" or blank

Comment: A straightforward way would be to take the four lines inside the `$.each` and also run them before the `$.each`, hardcoding the text.

Comment: So create and insert your blank option before the `$.each` in the same manner that you are doing inside the loop.

Comment: I am very new to JavaScript - would someone be willing to give an example?

Comment: Please post your attempt, so we can help you fix it. If you want to insert an element at the 1st position into an array, you can use `.unshift()`. (also, this question is solely about populating a `<select>` based on an array, ajax and Sharepoint are completely irrelevant)

Comment: Alright, screw it, here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/jgtq12uo/

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can just call .appendChild before your .each loop

```
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = "Please Select";
        option.value = "-1";
        ddlReason.appendChild(option);

        $.each(data.d.results, function( index, value ) 
        {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = value.Title;
            option.value = value.Id;
            ddlReason.appendChild(option);
        });
```

Comment: Fantastic! Worked perfectly - thank you!!  Is there a way to alert "Please select a Reason" if Reason=="Please Select"? onclick Save button

Comment: Yeah sure, here is a link to the fiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/Fernandog/bqLgo3yj/2/
You should also check out some javascript and jquery tutorials online.